# sed not recognizing matched group

Tags: bash, sed, git-bash

I'm trying to print out a sub string from all pdf files in a directory. I can't seem to make sed work with it. The regex is correct, but sed gives an error when I use \1

```
for old in ./*.pdf; do
    new=$(echo $old | sed -e 's/(\.\/)?\d+_(\w\w\-\d+).+/\1/')
    echo $new
done
```

I'm using sed (GNU sed) 4.4

The output is:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 32: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's
>   RHS

for each file in the directory...

Thanks!

Comment: `sed` only supports POSIX BRE/ERE patterns and you are feeding a PCRE pattern to it (while it expects a POSIX BRE one since you did not use `-r` nor `-E` options). It is not quite clear what you are trying to get, please provide a sample input with expected output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I changed it to "s/(\.\/)?[0-9]+_([A-Z][A-Z]\-[0-9]+).+/\1/" but it still gives the same error... Is it because sed version of RegEx can't match anything? Do I still have alien syntax in my regex?

Comment: POSIX BRE parses `+` as a literal `+`, escape it as well as `(` and `)`. Or do not escape them and use `-E` option to make it a POSIX ERE pattern. Then, you have 2 groups, why if you only replace with the contents of the first group? (The error you get is due to the fact you have no capturing group in `sed -e 's/(\.\/)?\d+_(\w\w\-\d+).+/\1/'`, `(` and `)` in a POSIX BRE pattern are literal `(` and `)` chars)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew using -E instead of -e works ! Thanks...

Comment: Ok,  `sed -E 's/(\.\/)?[0-9]+_[A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9]+.+/\1/'` works, too, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. I actually transformed my RegEx to that before testing :) thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -E 's/(\.\/)?[0-9]+_[A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9]+.+/\1/'
```

Note that `sed` does not support PCRE regex, thus, `\d` and `\w` are just plain invalid constructs here. To match any letter, you may use `[:alpha:]` POSIX character class, or if you wish to match uppercase letters, use `[:upper:]`.

Instead of `\d`, use `[0-9]` or `[:digit:]`.

In the BRE POSIX pattern, `(` and `)`  denote the literal parentheses, that is why you got an error saying you cannot refer to any capturing group value - there was none defined in the pattern. To make unescaped parentheses create a group in a POSIX BRE pattern, you need to escape them, or - if you use a POSIX ERE pattern (`sed` with `-r` or `-E` option), you may use them unescaped.

Same goes for `+` quantifier: in a POSIX BRE pattern it should escaped, in an ERE pattern, it is OK to use it unescaped.

Besides, you do not need to use a second capturing group since you are not using `\2` in the replacement.